# How do I save firefox web page as image

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please help me in saving web page as image using java.

I am using selenium web driver for an application, I need to take screenshot for an alert box.

So I thought it will be better if we have "save as image" button so that I can take the alert screenshot.

I am using firefox web driver

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: That is not the duplicate.. because I need the alert screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of firefox having new feature of executing commands by pressing SHIFT+F2

It helped me in taking alert screenshots, I used robot object for this but not using web driver

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install Firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/ and take any screenshot of web page.

Comment: but that will be become preprequisite for my application. I need solution that will automatically do this with java

Answer (score 0):

This robot function will help you  to take screenshot of displaying screen. You can edit it.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public void captureScreen(String fileName)throws Exception {
   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   Rectangle screenRectangle = newRectangle(screenSize);
   Robot robot = newRobot();
   BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
   ImageIO.write(image,"png",newFile(fileName));
}
```

Comment: I have seen it already but this requires keeping the window in maximize mode

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you.

```
File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File f = new File("Location to save your image ");
```